# Why does connecting to ec2 instance in browser fail so many times

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect to my ec2 instance from aws browser (EC2 instance connect > connect).

After trying maybe 10-20 times I do eventually manage but I see the following error message most of the time

```
There was a problem connecting to your instance
Log in failed. If this instance has just started up, wait a few minutes and try again. Otherwise, ensure the instance is running on an AMI that supports EC2 Instance Connect.
```

Is there a workaround to more reliably connect to ec2 instance from browser?

Comment: Once it connects, does it successfully connect every time after that? It could be that the instance was just starting up (as suggested by the error message).

Comment: no, it connects every 1/15 attempts or so and then fails after that

Comment: You are not providing enough information to get help. What kind of instance? Are you using your images or Amazon's images? What type of network configuration do you have? Do you allow instances to reach to AWS services directly or via a proxy? Once you reach the server, take a look at SSM logs to see if it is having trouble reaching to AWS ssm endpoints while trying to initialize a session when you click on connect. Check the version of SSM agent installed. etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to connect to an Amazon EC2 instance via SSH:

- Use [Connect using EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html), which provides a browser connection to the EC2 Connect service that then connects via SSH to the instance. The benefit is that no additional software or keypairs are required and authentication is managed via IAM. This requires Port 22 to be open to the IP range used by EC2 Instance Connect servers.
- Use [AWS Systems Manager **Session Manager**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html), which uses a software agent installed on the instance to establish a remote connection to the instance. It's not 'real' SSH, but it behaves much the same. The benefit is that it can be used to **access private instances** (since the agent 'punches through' to the Internet, rather than you connecting inwards to the instance) and IAM manages access.
- Use a **standard SSH** program to connect to the instance. This requires Port 22 to be open to your IP address and requires a keypair for authentication.

It is difficult to know what is causing your failures with EC2 Instance Connect. You could **try connecting via a different network** (eg home vs office vs tethered via your phone) to determine whether the network is having an impact. You could **check the CPU Utilization** of the instance to determine whether it is 'too busy' to handle the incoming connection (which would suggest the need for a larger Instance Type).